# How can I hide certain product at online store, but it must be available for purchase

Tags: php, laravel, shopify-app

I am creating a shipping insurance app in which I need to create a product, the requirement is that I don't want to show this product on store. App is working fine but the only issue that the shipping product is also visible along with other products.

I try to hide my product on the product setting, but it is not able to purchase since the system think it is an out of stock item, while I unchecked the button on the online store Visibility.

Please help to fixed this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a boolean field in the database 'is_shown' and select all products with `Product::where('is_shown', 1)->get()`. This way, you only select all products that are supposed to be shown. But you can still visit/use the product since it's still in the database.